# Problems with DAX query: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I'm stuck, and can't get past the message: "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Does anybody have an idea to what I'm doing wrong?

```
Testmeasure =
VAR SAEndDatePlusOneMonth =
    FIRSTDATE ( DATEADD ( Dato[Dato], 1, MONTH ) )
VAR SAStartDatePlusTwoMonths =
    FIRSTDATE ( DATEADD ( Dato[Dato], 2, MONTH ) )
VAR DoNotWithtake =
    CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( 'Målerpunkt'[Metering Point ID] ),
        FILTER (
            CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( FactSA ), ALL ( 'Dato' ) ),
            FactSA[SAStartDate] >= CALCULATE ( MIN ( Dato[Dato] ) )
                && FactSA[SAStartDate] < SAStartDatePlusTwoMonths
                && FactSA[SAEndDate] >= SAEndDatePlusOneMonth
        ),
        FILTER ( SA, NOT ( SA[SA status] IN { "Canceled", "Pending Start" } ) ),
        ALL ( Dato[Dato] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Målerpunkt'[Metering Point ID] ),
        FILTER (
            CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( FactSA[SAEndDate] ), ALL ( 'Dato' ) ),
            FactSA[SAEndDate] >= CALCULATE ( MIN ( Dato[Dato] ) )
                && FactSA[SAEndDate] < SAEndDatePlusOneMonth
        ),
        FILTER ( SA, SA[SA status] IN { "Stopped", "Closed" } ),
        FILTER (
            'Målerpunkt',
            NOT ( 'Målerpunkt'[Metering Point ID] IN { DoNotWithtake } )
        ),
        ALL ( Dato[Dato] )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that `VALUES ( 'Målerpunkt'[Metering Point ID] )` is returning multiple values but `CALCULATE` will only output a single value, not a list or table.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to replace your `CALCULATE` with a `CALCULATETABLE` for the calculation of the `VALUES` filter you are applying in the final expression.